# Is it possible to use Emacs "magit" to manage encrypted file with "git-crypt"?

Tags: git, encryption, emacs, magit

I would like to manage the versions of encrypted text file with Emacs,
with "git-crypt".

Emacs has the great encryption tool "epg", and git management tool "magit",
but combination of them can not handle encrypted file with git.

Is it possible to use Emacs "magit" to manage encrypted file with "git-crypt"?

Comment: What is the use case?

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason why not, after all it says in the readme:

> after git-crypt is set up (either with `git-crypt init` or `git-crypt unlock`), you can use git normally - **encryption and decryption happen transparently**.

But Magit has no explicit support, so you will have to do the initial  setup as  described in [Using git-crypt](https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt#using-git-crypt) manually.

> Emacs has the great encryption tool "epg",

This doesn't really enter the picture. Magit calls e.g. `git checkout`, Git consults `.gitattributes` and notices that it has to use `git-crypt`, `git-crypt` is called and uses whatever method it always uses to decrypt the files. Magit/Emacs/everything see those decrypted files.